# Восстановить R file

Tags: android

Привет всем. :)

У меня стёрся R file, как не пытался, не получается, пересмотрел все видео youtube, ничего не помогает.

Не подскажите, как можно вернуть?

Спасибо :)))

**Обновление**

> Error: R cannot be resolved to a
> variable

Проблема не в xml, в папке ген нету R file.

Comment: Исправить ошибки в xml файлах.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: он стирается и создается заново при каждом билде. Как написал @Suvitruf, чаще всего он не генерируется из за ошибок в ваших XML файлах.

Comment: @metalurgus справедливости ради, проблема может быть и в IDE, если автор юзает продукт от Jet Brains. У меня в одной версии был такой баг, они потом поправили его в след. версии.

Comment: мой проект был завершен, работал прекрасно, я сделал неправильный Export  R file сторса. Когда я делаю Build, ничего не происходит.

Comment: @metalurgus     юзает продукт от Jet Brains ---  что это?

Не могу сделать экспорт, нету R file.

Comment: сделайте правильный экспорт.    
продукт от Jet Brains - среда разработки INTELLIJ IDEA, которую разрабатывает JetBrains